# How to populate local instance of Wikibase with some selected data from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, knowledge-management, knowledge-graph

I set up a local instance of wikibase following [this guide](https://wikibase-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/local_wikibase_instance.html).

Now at http://localhost:8282 I can access a SPARQL interface which look very much like https://query.wikidata.org/ – good.

However, there seems to be no "preinstalled" data in my local instance, which is very reasonable.

To actually experiment how to add, remove and change data, I would like to copy a tiny fragment of the actual wikidata to my own instance. A particular task would be to get the [cats-example](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D) to return at least some matching records.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query to get RDF data:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 ;
                  rdfs:label ?itemLabel ;
                  skos:altLabel ?itemAltLabel ;
                  schema:description ?itemDescription .
          }
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Wikidata UI shows it as a table of triples "subject", "predicate", "object".

If you send the query to the SPARQL endpoint, you get back RDF data directly. (e.g. see [question 66968955](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968955/))

Comment: This seems to be the in the right direction. However, I still do no know what exactly should I do with the result of [this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#CONSTRUCT%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146...). I can download it in various formats but how can I insert it in *my* local wikibase instance?